# android imageview android:state_selected="true" not working

Tags: android, xml

I am using Image selector for changing my tab-widget image icons , when I selected any one of image view, image of that image view should change. For that i have used following code, but it is working good , but problem is **android:state_pressed="true"** is working but **android:state_selected="true"** not working in any image view , i am getting stuck from this issue , can anyone help me, answer will be appreciable.Thanks in advance.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_contacts_vippie_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_contacts_vippie"/>
```

Here is my Imageview:

```
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hiiMoblieContact"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/flexi_contact_selector" />
```

Comment: imageview doesn't save the state, use switch instead of image view and give image as backgrond of it.

Comment: @Android how ?? do you have any exmaple please guide me

Comment: @Android can you give me any link for that??

Comment: why dont you just add `android:clickable="true"` to your imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imageview doesn't save states. But don't worry, there is a workaround. Either use `toggleButtons` and set background **or** use `CheckableLinearlayout` **as parent of imageview**. Xml of imageview should be like this-

```
<package_name.CheckableLinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/hiiMoblieContact"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:duplicateParentState="true"
      android:src="@drawable/flexi_contact_selector"/>
  </package_name.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

The changes are highlighted in bold. Now you can handle the checkablelinearlayout's set checkedmethod. If for example you set the checkacle linearlayout's set checked true, the image will automatically change. You will have to make this `CheckableLinearLayout` class in your project and its link is - http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/CustomChoiceList/src/com.example.android.customchoicelist/CheckableLinearLayout.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of image view use toggle button or check-box or radio button. For example I am using check box.

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/hiiMoblieContact"
    android:button="@drawable/flexi_contact_selector"/>
```

**flexi_contact_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_contacts_vippie_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_contacts_vippie" />

</selector>
```

Hope this will help you..